# Play for Scala: function doesn't return

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

This most likely is a newbie question. Note that there's an if `1!=2` that doesn't work as the function prints "continues". What's wrong with the return?

```
def doSomething () = {  

      val json: JsValue = JsObject(Seq(
          "ret" -> JsString("1"),
          "msg" -> JsString("Some Msg")
      ))

      if (1 != 2)
         Ok(json))

      println("continues")

      Ok(json)
}
```

Comment: Put braces on your 'if' statement and/or indent the `println`. The `println` is being evaluated as a separate acttion.

Comment: ..and even after that, it will still print "continues" because `1 != 2` will always be `true`

Comment: that's the point that I'm trying to make. Since 1 != 2, then it should NOT print `continues` because `Ok()` returns the function in Play.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Play the `Ok` doesn't really finishes the function, and Scala just returns the result of the last process, in your example, it doesn't return the Ok inside the `if` because it still has code to run, try it with the print and second `Ok` inside an `else` and that way the method wouldn't have anything else to run if it enters the `if`

```
def doSomething () = {  

  val json: JsValue = JsObject(Seq(
      "ret" -> JsString("1"),
      "msg" -> JsString("Some Msg")
  ))

  if (1 != 2) {
     Ok(json))
  } else {
    println("continues")

    Ok(json)
  }
}
```

Comment: I have several validations that each will return with `Ok()` if they fail. There's no way to finish the function with Ok?

Comment: one option would be with `else if`, you could try using a `return Ok` but there is a chance it will give you an exception depending where you run it